# What it means for the wave equation of light in vacuum to be a solution of the maxwell equations?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, maxwell-equations

I know how to get the wave equation of light from Maxwell's equation, but I never understood why it is called the solution of the Maxwell equations. If say we have a positive charge standing still from our frame of reference, it generates an electric field that is solution of the Maxwell equations (Gauss law) but it does not propagate, it remains "fixed". I don't understand the difference between this electric field and the ones that do propagate freely through space, and how can it get "de-attached" from its source?

Comment: If you plug the wave formula for $\vec{E}(\vec{x}, t)$ and $\vec{H}(\vec{x},t)$ in to the left hand sides of Maxwell's equations, you get the expected right hand sides.

Comment: The inhomogeneous wave equation is not a solution of Maxwells equations, it is a consequence of it.

Comment: Maxwell equations have plenty of solutions, the solutions to the  wave equation is only one subset of of them. The wave equation can be derived from the ME's but the reverse is not true, so it does not replace the 4 Maxwell equations: you cannot recover the 4 Maxwell equations just from the wave equation.

Comment: @my2cts what do you mean by it is not a solution? Isnt it derived directly from Maxwells equations without vacumm?

Comment: @Wolphramjonny oh, so I missunderstood it as THE solution. And what is the difference between an electric ( and magnetic) field propagating through space and another "sticking" to the charge/current. It is just boundary conditions? Because they seem pretty unrelated phenomena

Comment: I mean that your title does not make sense. An equation is not a solution of an equation. The wave equation is not a solution of Maxwells equation. Can you reformulate it ? What are the Maxwell equations "without vacumm"? Do you have a spelling checker ?

Comment: @my2cts Right. By wave equation I meant the Electric field satisfying this equation, namely E=E_0 cos(wt-kx), and by maxwell equation without vacumm the ones where neither the charge density or density current are 0. I tought all the solutions must have the form of a wave, but now I see they are only a subset of them

Comment: A vacuum (not "vacumm") indicates the absence of everything except spacetime itself. How can something be "without" vacuum? Can you clarify the your question? Do you mean "how can a wave be a solution of the Maxwell equations" ?

Comment: @my2cts seems pretty clear to me, if vacuum means absence of charges, not having a vacuum will mean the opposite. My question is, if in a vacuum the electric field must obey a wave equation ( that is a consequence of maxwells equations in vacuum)  why the electric field generated by a positive charge doesnt propagate since everywhere is absent of charges except the point where the particle is

Comment: "Absence of vacuum" is a meaningless phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field of a charge in otherwise empty space obeys the wave equation everywhere but at the position of the charge. Because it has zero frequency it cannot propagate. It also is a solution of Poisson's equation, which has no propagating solutions.

To generate propagating, non zero frequency solutions, time dependent currents are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Maxwell equations are a set of 4 vectorial differential equations. Given a charge distribution and current (basically think of filling up space with things) that may or may not move, those equations will spit out an electric field and a magnetic field.

If you arrange your charge distribution in some specific ways, you can get propagating fields, or stationary ones. You are talking of a special distribution, which is empty space. Solving maxwell equations there gives us the wave equation that you know.

Now, if you want to have a propagating field emitted by something is space, you have to have that thing moving. Otherwise, the solution will not be time dependent (this is obvious from the maxwell equations themselves).

For example, you can think of an oscillating charge, in that case if you make the amplitude of the oscillation small enough and look far away, you can approximate the electric and magnetic field by a spheric wave with wavelength equal to the amplitude of the oscillation of the charge.